# AngularJs Authentication how to avoid flickering

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I am building an application with AngularJs and I want to prevent user from accessing application's internal pages if he is not logged in.

I have a separate application for login (loginApp) and for the main application (mainApp). What I have done so far in mainApp in order to support authentication is the following:

```
mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider. when('/apage', {
        templateUrl: ...,
        controller: ....,
        resolve: {
            load: function($q, AuthService){
                var defer = $q.defer();
                if(AuthService.notLoggedIn) {
                   defer.reject('user_not_logged_in');
                } else {
                   defer.resolve();
                }
                return defer.promise;
            }
        }
    }).run(function($rootScope, $window) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, next, current, rejection) {
            if (rejection === 'user_not_logged_in') {
                $window.location = '/html/pages/login.html';
            }
        });
    });
}])
```

My mainApp's html page is consisted of a navbar (which is controlled by controllers defined in navbarControllers module) and a div enclosing ng-view directive (partial pages go there).

My problem is that the code above works fine for the partial pages but not for the navbar. Navbar is loaded normally, its controllers try to make calls to backend but they fail (as user is not authenticated) so alerts popup and then redirects to login page. Why is this happening? How can I prevent navbarControllers module from loading and navbar from showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
  // code for your navbar which required user authentication
}
else {
  // navbar for logged out user.
}
```

Comment: Based on your idea I solved my problem using angular's ng-if directive on the navbar. If user is not authenticated it is hidden. Thank you!